# Access s3 files only from web application and localhost

Tags: javascript, html, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors

I'm developing an web application for which I host my files like images on s3. I want to access the files via URLs (not presigned URLs) in my img-tags like so:

```
<img src={'https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/mybucketname/imgs/myfile.jpg'} />
```

How can I restrict access to only my react application (for prod and dev)?

I tried using CORS with my deployed domain and localhost but that didn't work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>https://www.example.com</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedOrigin>https://example.com</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedOrigin>http://localhost:3000</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Comment: Note that allowing access "from localhost" doesn't really make sense, as a concept.  My computer is called "localhost" too.

Comment: Maybe you can use the [http-referer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-4) s3 policy for your use case. But as @Michael-sqlbot mentioned, using `localhost` might not be a good idea as my computer is called `localhost` too.

Comment: the localhost was just meant for developing purposes, in my production environment I'll remove `localhost` of course

Comment: @nickolay.laptev did solve it, thank you so much!

Comment: How was this solved? I do know how to restrict the policy to only allow my website, but how can I still get access to everything during development (as asked here)? (so in production I dont want to allow direct access for example, but during development I'd like to have direct access tot he files, but just myself)